# How to get execution ID for Google Cloud Functions triggered from HTTP?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write logs to Logging from Python applications by using Cloud Logging API Cloud client library with  "execution ID" that as same as google's default value.

[image]

**logger setup:**

```
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource


log_client = logging.Client()

# This is the resource type of the log
log_name = 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions'

# Inside the resource, nest the required labels specific to the resource type
res = Resource(type="cloud_function",
               labels={
                   "function_name": "my-function",
                   "region": "asia-east2"
               })
logger = log_client.logger(log_name.format("my-project"))
```

**write log:**

```
logger.log_struct({"message": request.remote_addr}, resource=res, severity='INFO')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible to do this using the purely the Cloud Function Framework itself, but you can try to extract the `executionId` from the request itself by using the following:

```
request.headers.get('function-execution-id')
```

I found an issue in Cloud Functions Github tracking the implementation of a native way to get those values, you can follow [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework/issues/34) for updates, if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using an older version of google-cloud-logging. I was able to get this functional using the [default python logging module](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python). In a cloud function running python 3.8 and google-cloud-logging==2.5.0, the executionId is correctly logged with logs, as well as the severity within stackdriver.

main.py:

```
# Imports the Cloud Logging client library
import google.cloud.logging
# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

# Retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment
# you're running in and integrates the handler with the
# Python logging module. By default this captures all logs
# at INFO level and higher
client.get_default_handler()
client.setup_logging()


# Imports Python standard library logging
import logging
def hello_world(req):
  # Emits the data using the standard logging module
  logging.info('info')
  logging.warning('warn')
  logging.error('error')
  return ""
```

requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-logging==2.5.0
```

Triggering this cloud function results in the following in stackdriver:
[image: python cloud function logging]